# Connecting Excel to Visio

Tags: excel, vba, visio

I'm trying to have Visio read data from Excel and create a drawing on Visio based on the information on the spreadsheet. Found this example that uses Access and C# to do what i'm trying to accomplish. Can anybody help me with this? I started by just creating the connection on excel to visio and i'm already stuck. Visio keeps giving me an error "Unable to connect to data". Here's what I have so far

```
Const excelFileName As String = "<C:\Users\Documents\Book2>"

Public Sub DrawVisio()

Dim doc As Visio.Document
Set doc = ActiveDocument

Dim cmd As String
Dim conString As String
Dim drs As Visio.DataRecordset

conString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
             "User ID=Admin;" & _
             "Data Source=" & excelFileName & ";" & _
             "Mode=Read;" & _
             "Extended Properties=""HDR=YES;IMEX=1;" & _
             "MaxScanRows=0;Excel 12.0;"";" & _
             "Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=34;"
    cmd = "select * from `Sheet1$`"
    Set drs = doc.DataRecordsets.Add(conString, cmd, 0, "Sheet1")
```

Comment: Do you actually have <> around the Excel file path? - I've not seen that before.  Probably also want to use the full workbook filename including the extension.

Comment: Removed  the <> in the path and added .xlsx and it's still giving me the same error. I ran this code from msdn and it didnt give me an error.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff765564.aspx 
Tried modifying the officepath and adding my file path. Still gives me  the same error

Comment: Are you running Visio Professional 2013?  The note on your link says "Data-connectivity features are available only to licensed users of Microsoft Visio Professional 2013"

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim xlWorkBookName As String
xlWorkBookName = "WorkbookName.xlsm"

Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Set xlApp = CreateObject("excel.application")

Dim pathExcel As String
pathExcel = Visio.ActiveDocument.Path & xlWorkBookName

Dim XlWrkBook As Excel.Workbook
Set XlWrkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(FileName:=pathExcel)
xlApp.Visible = True

Dim XlWrkSheet As Excel.Worksheet
Set XlWrkSheet = XlWrkBook.Sheets.Item("WorksheetName")
XlWrkSheet.Activate
```